# Why is this program giving no output?

Tags: c, if-statement, for-loop, break, continue

I have a program which is not working due to a for loop in it. I'm pasting a working snippet of code here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int numLoop = 19;
    int counter;
    int maxloops = 25;
    int takenNum1 = 9, takenNum2 = 14, takenNum3 = 17, takenNum4 = 21, takenNum5 = 24;

    for (counter=1; counter==maxloops; counter++)
    {
        printf("%d \n", counter);

        if (counter == numLoop)
        {
            break;
        }

        if (counter == takenNum1 || counter == takenNum2 || counter == takenNum3 || counter == takenNum4 || counter == takenNum5)
        {
            counter++;
            continue;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The expected output is: `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10 11 12 13 15 16 18 19`

Nothing is being printed.

Comment: You should compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...), improve your code till you get no warnings, then **use the debugger** (`gdb`). Your `for` loop is wrong.

Comment: Your *fix-my-code* question is off-topic here.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch extremely sorry. Is there a better format to ask this question in?

Comment: You should try to do your own homework. Did you read about how to use your debugger? See e.g. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/gnu_debugger/

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I admit I had not done my homework :P I am just starting out but thats no excuse for ignorance :)

Comment: I'll delete the question as I don't think it adds much value to other viewing it

Comment: But apparently I'm not allowed to do so! :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `for` loop condition appears buggy. You want to write `counter != maxloops` instead of `counter==maxloops`.

Otherwise, the loop condition is not met and the loop body is not at all executed.

That said, as per your requirement,

1. you need to move the checking block

   ```
   if (counter == takenNum1 || counter == takenNum2 || counter == takenNum3 || counter == takenNum4 || counter == takenNum5)
   {
       counter++;
       continue;
   }
   ```

   ***before*** the `printf()` statement to avoid *unconditional* printing.
2. The `for` loop condition should really look like

   ```
   for (counter=1; counter < numloop; counter++)
                            ^^^^^^^^^^
   ```

   as you want the output to be limited to `19`.

Comment: Apologies, for the above comment. My snippet worked with it but my original program didn't. Extremely sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @MythicCocoa In that case, you need to create a MCVE.

Comment: Ok thanks @SouravGhosh. Its working after a few other tweaks

Answer (score 1):

you may need to verify the logic. 
If the output needs to be maximum  of 19 iterations. Also, the inner-if condition should be checked before printing the counter.

sample pseudo code as below.

```
for (counter=1; counter<=numLoop; counter++)
{
    if (counter == takenNum1 || counter == takenNum2 || counter == takenNum3 || counter == takenNum4 || counter == takenNum5)
    {
        continue;
    }
 printf("%d \n", counter);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to take advantage of the teachable moment here. This appears to be a simple matter of misunderstanding the clauses in a `for` statement. A `for` statement is just a shortcut way to write a `while` loop, with the initialization and "after" code built in. The `for` statement has three clauses in its parenthesized list - `(init ; while ; after)`. So let's use as and example a `for` statement which is written as

```
for(i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
  {
  do_something();
  }
```

The above `for` loop could be rewritten using a `while` loop as

```
i = 0;

while(i < 10)
  {
  do_something();

  i++;
  }
```

As you can see, the `for` is a lot more compact.

Comment: I had misunderstood the meaning of the second clause :P

Answer (score 1):

Buddy ur code looks all messed up. understand the concept of looping. In for loop Listen to me closely.

U have kept the condition logically wrong.
The loop will check for condition. And you have written as the counter should equal to maxloop which will never satisfy in ur code as the code would exit wheb the counter reaches the value 19(break is given when the counter reaches 19). Hope that solves the first part.

Secondly please note that breaking of the loop should happen post displaying the values. For clear understanding i have given the code below. Hope this helps out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
int numLoop = 19;
int counter;
int maxloops = 25;
int takenNum1 = 9, takenNum2 = 14, takenNum3 = 17, takenNum4 = 21, takenNum5 = 24;
for (counter = 1; counter <= maxloops; counter++)
{
if (counter == takenNum1 || counter == takenNum2 || counter == takenNum3 || counter == takenNum4 || counter == takenNum5)
{
continue;
}
printf("%d \n", counter);
if (counter == numLoop)
break;
}
getchar();
return 0;
}
```